# KMM - Error Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I created a project to demo Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile. I built and ran it successfully on both devices: Android and iOS. After that, I re-ran the project on iOS. It had an error.

```
> Configure project :shared
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an Alpha feature. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html. To hide this message, add 'kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true' to the Gradle properties.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Volumes/Data/ProjectsKMM/DemoNetworkAPI/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh
(1 failure)
```

This is my project on Github [Click here](https://github.com/phongbm/KMM-DemoNetworkAPI). Please see it and help me to find the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use at least Kotlin 1.5.20 for `embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode` to be available (more info in https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/07/multiplatform-gradle-plugin-improved-for-connecting-kmm-modules/)

Comment: I use Jetpack Compose, it required to use Kotlin 1.5.10.

Comment: I have same issue here so using approach I wrote about in case you want to try that https://johnoreilly.dev/posts/kmm-using-different-kotlin-versions/

Comment: As you've probably seen, Jetpack Compose 1.0.1 has now been released and it works with Kotlin 1.5.21

Comment: Unfortunately the task not found in Kotlin 1.5.31, Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Pavel We had the same problem. There are few thing to know for resolving it: 1. this task wont appear on `gradlew tasks --all`, it is environment specific- it will only be available on MacOS with XCode installed. 2. this task cannot be run from terminal, you can only start it from XCode as Run Script. 3. You have to correctly setup your `build.gradle(.kts)` - we were trying to run this on ios emulator and we got the same error until we uncommented `iosSimulatorArm64` lines, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`embedAndSignPodAppleFrameworkForXcode` worked for me

Kotlin plugin version: 212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46

This was the suggestion from xcode/Android Studio regarding failed task

```
Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'. Some candidates are: 'embedAndSignPodAppleFrameworkForXcode'.
```