# KMM: embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode task not found

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kmm

I have created a basic KMM by following "Create your first app" guide
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-create-first-app.html

Then I've tried to build the framework with the following command from Terminal in Android Studio.
./gradlew :shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode

But I'm getting this error.
Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'.

Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Kotlin 1.5.31

There's a similar question on SO. People say that embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode should work with Kotlin 1.5.20 at least.
[KMM - Error Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639738/kmm-error-task-embedandsignappleframeworkforxcode-not-found-in-project-sha)
But it doesn't in my setup.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

UPDATE
The task is running perfectly fine when launched form XCode/Build Phases script.
Somehow it is not able to launch from terminal (Android Studio or system one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode is not supposed to run from the terminal as packForXCode used be.

The proper way to run this task is from XCode build system.

Anyway, I was able to run embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode from terminal after exporting the following variables.

```
export CONFIGURATION\=Debug
export ARCHS\=x86_64
export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY\=-
export FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH\=iosApp.app/Frameworks
export SDK_NAME\=iphonesimulator15.0
export TARGET_BUILD_DIR\="../build/ios/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator"
```